# How can I use PHP to carry the main html elements across multiple pages (eg have a html shell)

Tags: php, html

I wish to use PHP to use the same html shell across multiple, so that I only have to make changes to one page instead of multiple.

Apparently there is only one line that is needed.

Comment: Out of close votes for today, but possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818135/how-to-use-php-include-to-insert-an-html-stub-across-all-pages-in-a-website?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Just simply move the code that are used many time in your many php file in separate php file and use in three ways

`<?php include 'filename.php';?>//suppose not found then include will only produce a warning (E_WARNING) and the script will continue`

`<?php require 'filename.php';?>//suppose not found require will produce a fatal error (E_COMPILE_ERROR) and stop the script`

`<?php require_once 'filename.php'; ?>//include only once in whole same PHP file`

I hope it clear you.....

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new file and put all of your html in there then add this code to every page you want to have that files contents:

```
<?php require_once 'filename.php'; ?>
```